# Ponteiro altera o valor dentro de função em C++

Tags: c++, funções, ponteiro

Tenho a tarefa de criar quatro funções que fazem multiplicação, divisão, soma e subtração entre dois números dados pelo usuário. A operação a ser realizada deve ser escolhida através dos caracteres * / - +, dados pelo usuário.

Devo usar ponteiros para fazer as operações, o ponteiro para o primeiro número funciona bem, mas o segundo, quando entra na função, sempre altera o valor para 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int mult(int *a, int *b)
{
    return *a *= *b;

}

float div(int *a, int *b)
{
    return *a /= *b;

}

int sub(int *a, int *b)
{
    return *a -= *b;

}

int soma(int *a, int *b)
{
    return *a += *b;

}


int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    char op;

    printf("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("\nDigite o segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("\nNumeros: %d e %d", num1, num2);

    printf("\nDigite a operacao a ser realizada (* / - +): ");
    scanf("%s", &op);

    if (op == '*')
    {
        printf("\n%d * %d = %d\n", num1, num2, mult(&num1, &num2));

    }else if(op == '/')
    {
    printf("\n%d / %d = %f\n", num1, num2, div(&num1, &num2));

    }else if(op == '-')
    {
        printf("\n%d - %d = %d\n", num1, num2, sub(&num1, &num2));

    }else if (op == '+')
    {
        printf("\n%d + %d = %d\n", num1, num2, soma(&num1, &num2));

    }else
    {
        printf("\nOperacao invalida\n");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

O que está acontecendo e porque um ponteiro se difere do outro se estão implementados da mesma maneira?

Comment: Por que você faz `return *a *= *b` ao invés de `return *a * *b`. Você precisa que o primeiro argumento contenha o resultado ao voltar da função?

Comment: Olá, preciso apenas retornar o resultado. Tentei da maneira `return *a * *b` mas o segundo ponteiro continua com o valor 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As contas nas suas funções estão erradas. Você devia usar +, -, *, / ao invés de +=, -=, *= e /=.

E acredito que o erro aconteça quando o programa tenta ler o caractere da operação. O correto seria:

```
scanf(" %c", &op); //com espaço antes do %c
```

Obs: por que você está usando printf e scanf ao invés de std::cout e std::cin ?

Comment: Achei que menção ao `cin` foi superdigno a uma pergunta de c++

Comment: Corrigi com o " %c" e deu tudo certo, as operações estão sendo feitas corretamente. Já o printf e scanf virou um costume utilizar, kkkk.

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando o resultado do valor de suas operações em `num1`.

O que você está fazendo é semelhante a:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2  = 5;
num1 += num2;
```

Agora o valor de `num1` é o resultado da operação: 5.

O que você deseja é `return num1 + num2` ou em dereferenciação de ponteiros: `return *a + *b`. O que retorna a soma dos valores e não adiciona a variável `num1` o resultado.

É só retirar o `=` das operações.

Note também que apesar da função retornar float você deve converter explicitamente os valores para float em sua divisão.

```
float div(int *a, int *b)
{
    return (float)*a / (float)*b;
}
```